# How to configure SharePoint REST API to return JSON by default?

Tags: web-services, rest, json

I'm using a 3rd party HTTP client to retrieve data from SharePoint. I want to get the result in JSON format. I know one method is to add the header "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"

However, the 3rd party library does not let me specify custom headers. Would it be possible to make SharePoint default to JSON, or is there a special URL query parameter I can use?

The HTTP client is written in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Get a different 3rd party library?

Comment: Good point, and that's what I ended up doing. The 3rd party lib did something more than just HTTP though, so I had to wrap those in my own lib.